# Is There Already Evidence Supporting Stapp's Theory of the Causally Efficacious Human Will?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

Physicists J. Acacio de Barros and Gary Oas wrote a paper titled “Can we Falsify the Consciousness-Causes-Collapse Hypothesis in Quantum Mechanics?” published in the Foundations of Physics, 47(10):1294-1308 (2017). [Preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.00614).

The article notes correctly that Henry Stapp is the best known contemporary supporter of the von Neumann Interpretation (which they term the Consciousness Causes Collapse Hypothesis, CCCH). The article **mentions** but doesn't examine Stapp's claims that the conscious mind can affect the brain via the Quantum Zeno effect and that the impact of this effect would be visible to researchers who look for evidence of simple harmonic oscillators. In a short [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.5569) that de Barros and Oas don't cite, Stapp has identified a physicist, Efstratios Manousakis, who has done work providing quantitative evidence supporting Stapp's claims. [Preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.4516)

Unfortunately, instead of evaluating the claimed evidence, the authors present two dubious arguments. First, they note that CCCH is an example of (interactive) substance dualism; and, therefore, would have a problem with the (alleged) principle of causal closure (a **philosophical** principle holding, roughly, that any physical effect has a sufficient physical cause). This begs question, since Stapp is claiming to show that empirical evidence falsifies the causal closure principle.

Secondly, de Barros and Oas revisit a thought experiment involving trained cockroaches which they proposed in a previous paper  [QUANTUM MECHANICS & THE BRAIN, AND SOME OF ITS CONSEQUENCES](http://www.cosmosandhistory.org/index.php/journal/article/viewFile/507/847). After reviewing its feasibility, they conclude that it is completely unfeasible. At this point they reach the final conclusion of the journal article: that the CCCH is unfalsifiable. Not just not falsifiable by experiments with trained cockroaches, but not falsifiable **by any means**, a much bigger leap.

I would like to invite forum members to lend their expertise to the task of evaluating Stapp's evidentiary claims in a more scientifically respectable manner. Is there evidence where Stapp says there is?

Comment: You posted a very similar question not long ago...

Comment: actually: this one https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/495125/how-is-it-possible-that-consciousness-causes-collapse-interpretations-of-qm-are is quite closely related.

Answer (score 3):

I have not seen Manousakis's model before this moment, and I write in some haste as this question is likely to be closed soon. But I just want to point out some of the outlandish features that such models possess.

Stapp's concept is apparently that the world is objectively in a superposition, and then objectively jumps or "collapses" into a particular component of that superposition, as a result of a choice of physical brain observables made by a mind separate from the physical world; and then this process recurs throughout a human lifetime. The sequence of conscious moments that we experience, is therefore literally a series of quantum measurements of brain observables, the brain going into superposition via Schrodinger evolution, then projecting onto a determinate conscious state when a choice of observables is made, and so forth in alternation.

(I could be getting some details wrong, as I said I am writing in haste, and I may need to correct this answer afterwards. But I do think this is the essence of Stapp's concept.)

The outlandish thing is simply that the superposition in question is not going to be confined to the brain. Because everything is connected by entangling local interactions, the superposition that will be reduced by the next observer choice, will extend beyond the observer's body into the environment. It will be a decohered superposition owing to the thermal nature of the interactions, but nonetheless, we are not just talking about a superposition in a part of the brain, that is periodically and spontaneously collapsing, but rather a superposition stretching into the world at large.

In a sense there is no problem here that is not faced by other attempts to interpret quantum mechanics. The true and original Copenhagen interpretation (as opposed to the bastardized 'consciousness-causes-collapse' version, with its reification of the wavefunction) says that superpositions are not real things, because wavefunctions are not real things, but then has nothing to say about what is actually happening between 'measurements'. The many-worlds interpretation says the wavefunction is real and every part of it is always real, and that's why there are many worlds, but is unable to give any coherent and convincing details about exactly how to divide up the wavefunction into worlds, and why the Born probability rule is observed to hold.

So every approach to quantum mechanics has to deal with the problem of superpositions of arbitrary extent, it is not a unique sin of Stapp's. But I wanted to try to make clear (I do not know if I have succeeded), just what kind of world-picture is under consideration here: a world which is constantly going into superposition, undergoing a many-worlds kind of branching, but which is then periodically being locally pruned by selections of brain observables, made by disembodied observer-minds.

Manousakis writes about binocular rivalry. This is a phenomenon in which contradictory images are presented to both eyes simultaneously, and the images then take turns being what is consciously perceived. Apparently he has some data about the time that the rival images spend at the fore of consciousness, and claims that he can motivate this with a Stapp-like model of (coupled?) oscillators being observed-and-reduced by an observer-mind.

If you ask how orthodox neuroscience explains the alternation of conscious images that occurs in binocular rivalry, you will instead hear about e.g. the idea that the reticular activating system stimulates the left and right hemispheres in turn, and that it is this alternating stimulation which causes first one image, and then the other, to be the consciously perceived image. I have no idea if this particular theory is popular or plausible among neuroscientists, it's just a particular theory that I know about due to its originator(?), the recently deceased neuroscientist Jack Pettigrew; which I use for the purpose of concrete illustration. My point is that a "sensible" neuroscientific theory of the alternation phenomenon, is going to involve some kind of classical neuronal dynamics; rather than a stochastic collapse onto one of two quantum basis states, triggered by the choice of a discorporate observer-mind.

Even without yet examining Manousakis's calculations, I can tell you that they will offer "evidence" for Stapp's proposition so slender as to almost count for nothing, because they must be so disconnected from any specific anatomical or biophysical facts. They will just be of the form "let us suppose there are oscillators, and that they are described thus, then they will exhibit a certain kind of behavior". The conclusions will presumably be mathematically correct, given the premises; but that will be completely outweighed by the lack of grounding in biological reality.

You may regard all this as a prediction, regarding what I will find when I really read the papers. Now to take a closer look...